# QGIS filter to get a mesh or fishnet with spaces without information

Tags: qgis, python, clip, mesh, rstudio

Can I create a filter with a Python code or R code, to eliminate the spaces that don't belong to the orange shape file? I was thinking in to each shapefile meshed, assign an area from orange shapefile. Or should I raster the orange file in order to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In the QGIS *Processing Toolbox* search for *Extract by Location*.  Extract those feature from the orange polygon shapefile that intersect your fishnet.  This will result in a new shapefile.
[See this link for more information on the full suite of Vector Selection Tools](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html).

See below for an example of the *Extract by Location* dialog box.

If you did not want to create a new shapefile you could use the *Select by Location* tool, start editing those data, reverse the selection, and delete the non-intersecting fishnet polygons.  Edit your post if that is the path you want to take.
[image]